# How do i find closest UL tag from current element-jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html-lists

```
My html structure is like below

<h3><span class="mw-headline">Zone1</span></h3>
<ul>
<li>District 1 of Zone1</li>
<li>District 2 of Zone1</li>
<li>District 3 of Zone1</li>
</ul>
<h3><span class="mw-headline">Zone2</span></h3>
<ul>
<li>District 1 of Zone2</li>
<li>District 2 of Zone2</li>
<li>District 3 of Zone2</li>
</ul>
```

I need to pull all zone and districts on json like below

```
[
  {
    "zone": "Zone1",
    "districts": [
      "District 1 of Zone1",
      "District 2 of Zone1",
      "District 3 of Zone1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "zone": "Zone2",
    "districts": [
      "District 1 of Zone2",
      "District 2 of Zone2",
      "District 3 of Zone2"
    ]
  }
]
```

my jquery looks like below

```
$('.mw-headline').each( function() {
    var state=$( this ).html();
    $(this).closest('ul').find('li').each(function()  { //i need the closest ul and iterate it
        alert($( this ).prop('tagName'));
    });

});
```

i need to find the  closest `ul` of current object and iterate `li`  , as a result which i can put on array.

But it is not working .. anu clue what i missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `next` of `parent` to select the `ul`.

```
$(this).parent().next('ul').find('li').each(function(){...})
```

This will work for full problem

```
var zones = [];

$('.mw-headline').each( function() {
    var obj = {zone:'',districts:[]};
    obj.zone = $(this).text();

    $(this).parent().next('ul').find('li').each(function(){
        obj.districts.push($(this).text());
    });
    zones.push(obj);
});
console.log(zones)
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/99/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to find its parent first:

```
$(this).parent().closest('ul')
```

Even better would be to use prev or next:

```
 $(this).parent().next('ul') // to find next ul
```

Or,

```
$(this).parent().prev('ul') //to find previous ul
```